# Плавное скрытие блоков

Tags: javascript

Перерыл весь интернет в поисках решения, но всё не то. Есть скрытые блоки, которые по нажатию на радио плавно выезжают и заезжают при повторном нажатии

```js
function spoiler(el) {
var text = el.parentNode.querySelector(".spoilerText");

text.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.spoilerText {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.spoilerText {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.spoilerText.active {
  max-height: 190px;
}

.spoilerText span {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
   <input type="radio" name ="radio" id="ПервыйБлок" onclick="spoiler(this)">
   <label for="ПервыйБлок">Фрукты</label>

   <div class="spoilerText" id="фрукты">
    <a href="#">Абрикос</a> <br>
    <a href="#">Авокадо</a> <br>
    <a href="#">Айва</a> <br>
    <a href="#">Алыча</a>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="подменю">
   <input type="radio" name ="radio" id="ВторойБлок" onclick="spoiler(this)">
   <label for="ВторойБлок">Овощи</label>

   <div class="spoilerText">
    <a href="#">Картофель</a> <br>
    <a href="#">Лук</a> <br>
    <a href="#">Чеснок</a>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div>
   <input type="radio" name ="radio" id="Остальное">
   <a href="#">
   <label for="Остальное">Остальное</label>
   </a>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Как при нажатии на 2 радио свернуть 1, а при нажатии 3 свернуть 2. То есть оставаться должен тот блок, где активна радио кнопка. Нужна совместимость с IE11. Спасибо!

Comment: Вариант CSS: `input[name="radio"]:checked ~ .spoilerText {max-height: 190px;}`

Comment: Вариант JS: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.spoilerText'), function(item) {item.className = 'spoilerText ' + (item === el.parentElement.querySelector('.spoilerText') ? 'active' : '');});` К сожалению непонятно, что делать с `id="Остальное"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменил в HTML type=radio на type=checkox так как лучше использовать type=checkbox для текущей задачи, та как у type=radio нет нативного способа отключить чекбокс при повторном клике.
Css правило взял у @Рустам Гимранов так же удалил не принадлежащий css к текущей задаче.
Если нужно что бы табы скрывались плавно, то нужно перенести строку в css

```
 transition: max-height 1s;
```

из правила

```
input[name='radio']:checked ~ .spoilerText {
```

в правило

```
.spoilerText {
```

```js
const checkBoxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')];

const onClickHandler = e => {
  const { target } = e;
  toggleTabs(checkBoxes, target); // передаем в нашу функцию текущий чекбокс что бы все отфильтровать кроме текущегочекбокса

  target.checked = target.checked; // чекаем только текущий чекбокс
};

const toggleTabs = (checkBoxes, currentCheckbox) => {
  // создаем функцию что бы можно было вызвать при клике

  checkBoxes
    .filter(key => key !== currentCheckbox) // фильтруем массив чекбоксов исключая текущий чекбокс
    .forEach(checkbox => {
      checkbox.checked = false; // убрать все чекбоксы
      checkbox.removeEventListener('click', onClickHandler); // убрать все слушатели по клику которые были до этого
      checkbox.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
    });
};

toggleTabs(checkBoxes);
```

```css
.spoilerText {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.spoilerText {
  max-height: 0;
}

input[name='radio']:checked ~ .spoilerText {
  transition: max-height 1s;
  max-height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="ПервыйБлок" />
        <label for="ПервыйБлок">Фрукты</label>

        <div class="spoilerText" id="фрукты">
          <a href="#">Абрикос</a> <br />
          <a href="#">Авокадо</a> <br />
          <a href="#">Айва</a> <br />
          <a href="#">Алыча</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="подменю">
        <input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="ВторойБлок" />
        <label for="ВторойБлок">Овощи</label>

        <div class="spoilerText">
          <a href="#">Картофель</a> <br />
          <a href="#">Лук</a> <br />
          <a href="#">Чеснок</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="Остальное" />
        <a href="#">
          <label for="Остальное">Остальное</label>
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```